# Python: Using only recursion, make a pyramid pattern with an asterisk in between every time

Tags: python, recursion

> Rules: You can only use 1 argument, 1 print and 1 def while using
> recursion.
>
> So it will look something like this:
>
> ```
> def pattern(n):
>
>     **Your code here**
> ```

There are 4 scenarioes.

pattern(0)

(No output)

pattern(1)

```
*
```

pattern(2)

```
*
**
*
```

patterns(3) will output

```
*
**
*
***
*
**
*
```

This is my code:

```
def stars(n, descending=True):
    if descending:
        print('*' * n)
        if n > 2:
            print('*', '\n', end='')

    if n == 1:
        if not descending:
            print('*')
        return

    stars(n - 1, descending)
    if not descending:
        print('*' * n)
        print('*', '\n', end='')


stars(5, descending=False)
stars(4)
```

How do I solve this question? I could do it but I used 2 arguments, 2 prints and it only works for 3 and above. Any help would be appreciated!

My answer (edit):

```
def pattern(n):
    if n > 0:
        pattern(n-1)
        print('*' * n)
        pattern(n-1)
    else:
        return


pattern(3)
```

This fits the question perfectly, but I assume there isn't a way to do pattern(4) and above?

Comment: Can you show the code you've already written that uses two args?

Comment: Hint: `pattern(2)` is `pattern(1)`, then `'*'` 2 times, then `pattern(1)` again

Comment: Sure, I'll edit it now

Comment: Ooh I kinda see it now and pattern(3) is pattern(2) then '*' 3 times then pattern(2) but I'm not sure how to code it recursively with the limitations

Comment: Are you sure this is a vertical pyramid and not a horizontal one? This detail would change the problem.

Comment: Yeah it is vertical

Comment: @Thac the limiter is: when you detect n=0, you immediately terminate the function without printing anything

Comment: Hmm so is there no way to solve this?

Comment: qrsngky told you how to do it

Comment: It's just a hint but I'll try and see if I can do it while meeting the requirements.

Comment: How do I return the previous pattern to the top and bottom? I can only return to the bottom so it will look like pattern(3), pattern(2) instead of 2 3 2

Comment: The pattern does not need to return anything, as it is only printing.

Answer (score 2):

```
def pattern(n):
    if n > 0:
        pattern(n-1)
        print(n * "*")
        pattern(n-1)
```

---

The output is as you wish, for example

```
>>> pattern(3)
```

> ```
> *
> **
> *
> ***
> *
> **
> *
> ```

Comment: is it considered recursive even if I do not use else: return?

Comment: @Thac: It is recursion as it is described in terms of itself, but it does not explicitly mark the base case

Comment: @Thac, `return` is not mandatory; it has meaning only in the case the function returns something other than `None`, or if it is desirable to finish the execution in the other place as its natural end (i.e., when there are no more instructions to perform).

Answer (score 1):

```
def stars(n: int):
    num_range = list(range(1, n))
    num_range = num_range + num_range[0:-1][::-1]
    num_range = num_range + [n] + num_range
    for x in num_range:
        print("*" * x)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I don't think this is the pattern the OP is talking about. (check it for n=3)

Comment: Yeah there's an asterisk in between and also it must be recursion with limitations so I'm kinda stumped

Comment: my bad, apologies, will correct it

Comment: hmm I see, but it need to be recursive do I'm not sure if that's accepted

Answer (score 1):

"Recursion occurs when a thing is defined in terms of itself or of its type." (Wikipedia)
So, try to describe a pattern in terms of others, for example pattern(3) in terms of other patterns.

From the samples, one can see that pattern(3) is "pattern(2), then '*' 3 times, then pattern(2)" (and similarly with other samples other than n=0), but the pattern(0) is a special case to be handled.

```py
def pattern(n):
    if n == 0: # base case 
        pass # this case does nothing
    else: # recursive case:
        pattern(n-1)
        print('*' * n)
        pattern(n-1)
```

It's also possible to simplify using `if n > 0:` without else, as [MarianD's  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73147797/4225384) shows it. (I intentionally distinguish base case and recursive case here for illustration purposes, but it's not necessary in recursion)

Note that the demo will throw errors for invalid values:

- n is negative number: RecursionError (base case never reached before it hits the limit)
- n is non-integer positive number: In my demo, it keeps subtracting by 1 and the base case is never reached, too, so it ends up in RecursionError. But in any case, the string cannot be multiplied with n.
- n is string: TypeError when trying n-1
  etc.

It's possible to modify the program to handle those cases (depending on what you want, here I just let it err).

One can use a loop to check print it from 0 to 5:

```
for n in range(6):
    print(f"n={n}:")
    pattern(n)
    print('')
```

output:

```
n=0:

n=1:
*

n=2:
*
**
*

n=3:
*
**
*
***
*
**
*

n=4:
*
**
*
***
*
**
*
****
*
**
*
***
*
**
*

n=5:
*
**
*
***
*
**
*
****
*
**
*
***
*
**
*
*****
*
**
*
***
*
**
*
****
*
**
*
***
*
**
*
```

Check if the patterns 4 and 5 are exactly what you want.

Comment: Well I just did if n > 0 it works so there won't be an error and I don't know what pattern 4 and 5 is so it should be correct, thanks!